# Mysql Join and Order

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables that have same columns,but different data ( deposits,withdrawals,transfers )

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   `withdrawals` (   `id` int(11) NOT
>   NULL auto_increment,   `user`
>   varchar(12) default NULL,   `amount`
>   double(12,2) default NULL,   `date`
>   timestamp NULL default
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `time`
>   varchar(50) default NULL,   `type`
>   varchar(50) default NULL,   `status`
>   varchar(1) default '0',   `notes` PRIMARY KEY 
>   (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

I want to merge all 3 tables into 1 table and order them by all their dates and show a row only if user='$user'

```
Example if table 1 has this data
id  user    amount  date        time    type            status          notes
2   vveer   142.00  2010-04-01 03:05:01 PayPal              2          deposit
3   test11  116.00  2010-04-01 10:33:23 PayPal              2          deposit

Example if table 2 has this data
id  user    amount  date        time    type            status          notes
3   vveer   142.00  2009-04-01 03:05:01 PayPal              2          withdraw
7   test11  112.00  2010-04-12 10:33:23 PayPal              2          withdraw

Example if table 3 has this data
id  user    amount  date        time    type            status          notes
5   test11  133.00  2010-03-01 10:33:23 PayPal              2          transfer
7   test11  123.00  2010-02-01 10:33:23 PayPal              2          transfer

I want to show all data for user test11 ordered by dates(is like putting all the dates together and ordering by 1 date column ) .
3   test11  112.00  2010-04-12 10:33:23 PayPal              2          withdraw
7   test11  116.00  2010-04-01 10:33:23 PayPal              2          deposit
5   test11  133.00  2010-03-01 10:33:23 PayPal              2          transfer
5   test11  123.00  2010-02-01 10:33:23 PayPal              2          transfer
```

Comment: Why isn't the schema like that to begin with? You should just have one transactions table and a type column instead of 3 different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this case is what the UNION operator is designed for. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp for more information.